# SparkSession does not exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to define a udf in Spark 2.3.0 using Scala 2.11.12. It seems to me that I need to use `SparkSession.udf()` to be able to do this, from reading the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession).

But I can't import this object,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
```

leads to:

```
Error:(2, 8) object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
```

Here is my build.sbt:

```
name := "webtrends-processing-scala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.3"

libraryDependencies += "io.lemonlabs" %% "scala-uri" % "1.4.3"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must include **spark sql** dependence:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0",
                            "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql"  % "2.3.0")
```